# generating CFG for whole source code with LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, control-flow-graph

Does anyone from LLVM community know if there is a way to generate CFG for the whole input source code using `opt -dot-cfg foo.ll(.bc)` ? as this one generates the CFG per function thus the connections between functions will be ignored.

It seems that the older analyze tool has depreciated.

Comment: That's ICFG, but llvm doesn't have accurate callgraph to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if you found any way to get interprocedural CFG. I found that inlining call functions by other inliner passes might be helpful but I couldn't be able to get it to work yet. I've posted this 
[Finding all possible paths in a c/c++ program by LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337703/finding-all-possible-paths-in-a-c-c-program-by-llvm)